# SQL Query join issue between two tables

Tags: sql, join, select, syntax

I'm new to SQL and I need help with how to select two tables and display the data.

I want to get the `Name` from `Products` and `Description` and `Bestbefore` from the second table `ProductDescription`.

`Products` table:

```
Id
Name
Quantity
Price
```

`ProductDescription`:

```
Id
Description
BestBefore
ProductId
```

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM Products 
INNER JOIN ProductDescriptions Description, BestBefore;
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using the correct syntax. All the columns you want to query should be in the select list. Additionally, you're missing a join condition:

```sql
SELECT     Name, Description, BestBefore
FROM       Products p
INNER JOIN ProductDescriptions pd ON p.Id = pd.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to chose the columns you want, *then* join the tables.

```
SELECT p.name, d.description, d.bestbefore
FROM products p
INNER JOIN productdescription d
ON p.id = d.id
```